# transform a square matrix into column wise matrix using pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new to python. I have a square matrix and want to transform it to a column wise matrix using pandas dataframe. Its a fairly large matrix 1,000 x 1,000. An example below of what I need. I'm stumped! Any help greatly appreciated - thanks!!!

```
import pandas as pd

# square matrix
data = {'Zone': ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3'],
        'Z1': [10, 3, 1],
        'Z2': [2, 5, 1],
        'Z3': [1, 2, 5]}
 
df_square = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_square)

# this is what I need to generate
data = {'Origin_zone': ['Z1', 'Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z2', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z3', 'Z3'],
        'Destination_zone': ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3'],
        'Value': [10, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5]  
        }

df_column = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(
    df_square.set_index("Zone")
    .T.stack()
    .rename_axis(["Origin_zone", "Destination_zone"])
    .reset_index(name="Value")
)
```

Prints:

```
  Origin_zone Destination_zone  Value
0          Z1               Z1     10
1          Z1               Z2      3
2          Z1               Z3      1
3          Z2               Z1      2
4          Z2               Z2      5
5          Z2               Z3      1
6          Z3               Z1      1
7          Z3               Z2      2
8          Z3               Z3      5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas.melt() would work in this scenario: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

You could do:

```
df_melted = pd.melt(df_square, id_vars=['Zone'], var_name='Destination_zone', value_name='Value')
df_melted.rename(columns={'Zone': 'Origin_zone'}, inplace=True)
df_melted
```

Output:

```
Origin_zone Destination_zone  Value
0          Z1               Z1     10
1          Z2               Z1      3
2          Z3               Z1      1
3          Z1               Z2      2
4          Z2               Z2      5
5          Z3               Z2      1
6          Z1               Z3      1
7          Z2               Z3      2
8          Z3               Z3      5
```